# How to URL encode parameters in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, urlencode

I have the following code in my view:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
           "View item", 
           "Index", 
            "Items", 
            new 
            { 
                itemName = Model.ItemName 
            }, 
            null) %>
```

I have a problem when the item name contains a sharp (#) or the percent symbol (%).

- When the item name is `"name#with#sharp#"`, the controller receives only the first part of the name until the first sharp (only receives `"name"`).
- When the item name is `"name%with%percent"` I get an error: ***HTTP error 400 - Bad request.***

I not sure if this is a problem with the URL encoding, because it works with other conflictive chars such as:

```
;
=
+
,
~
[blank]
```

Do you know how could I address this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What urls are getting generated?  When I try your example above with the '%' symbols, I get this:  `http://localhost/AspNetMvc2/Items?itemName=name%25with%25percent`, and no errors.  Also, the example with the `#` symbol produces this:  `http://localhost:55386/Items?itemName=name%23with%23sharp%23`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a route setup and your url looks something like this:

http://localhost/Items/Index/name%25with%25percent - (this will blow up)

as opposed to this:

http://localhost/Items/Index/?itemName=name%25with%25percent - (query string is ok)

So an option would be to remove the "itemName" property from your route (in your RouteCollection) so that Html.ActionLink will render the Url using itemName as a QueryString parameter.

As @Priyank says, the problem is because the itemName is part of the Url (not a QueryString parameter) and it contain illegal characters.

Comment: Yes, you're assuming right. So the only place to use % symbol is a query string. Is there any other way to use % in the URL?

Answer (score 4):

Since these routedvalues are posted as part of URL string, they will be treated as separate values, separated by # and %. There are couple options for handle your case.

You will have to implement your custom `ValueProvider (IValueProvider and especially RouteDataValueProvider)` to handle your custom need. One programmer had an issue with character '/' and he hacked it here http://mrpmorris.blogspot.com/2012/08/asp-mvc-encoding-route-values.html

Second is to store values in TempData which persists across two request and use them.

Hope this helps to think in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use the UrlHelper instance of your view to do this for you. Try giving this a shot:

`<%= Html.ActionLink(
           "View item", 
           "Index", 
            "Items", 
            new 
            { 
                itemName = Url.Encode(Model.ItemName)
            }, 
            null) %>`

**Update**

After testing, it seems explicitly encoding like I did above seems to be **less** accurate and will cause the server to double-encode (eg - % will come out as %2525 in the url).

Comment: This is not enough. IIS is converting name+hello into name%25%2bhello that fails with a bad request

Comment: Comes out fine for me whether I encode or not. 200 status code across the board. It actually seems most accurate when I **don't** encode, and just let routing and IIS do their thing normally. Just tested in Casini and IIS Express with your url with sharps (#), percents (%), and plusses (+) examples. What version of IIS are you using?

Comment: to reproduce the problem you will have to setup a route with a token called itemName - so the url looks something like: localhost/Items/Index/name%25with%25percent - this url contains illegal characters

Comment: @LeeGunn Thanks for the tip. Seems in my tests the url with sharps (#) still works fine w/ the route token defined. The percent (%) triggers asp.net request validation, and the plusses (+) returns a 404. I tried the fix @Priyank suggested and that seemed to work. Looks like he's got the answer. If I had the rep to, I'd upvote him. :)