# C# WebAPI Core Backslash in Route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, url-encoding, backslash

We have a Webapi that should be able to get data based on the passed user. this user includes a domain, so the parameter is something like `Domain\Username`.

In the end our API-Call should look like this:
http://servername/api/controller/`Domain\Username` 
or encoded
http://servername/api/controller/`Domain%5CUsername`

Both URLs return Not Found and the controller is not fired (breakpoint does not hit)

I have found this, which says that you cannot pass %-Values to URL directly. 
 [Pass in Active Directory user name (DOMAIN\etc) in asp.net MVC URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429824/pass-in-active-directory-user-name-domain-etc-in-asp-net-mvc-url) and this [How to URL encode parameters in ASP .NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901049/how-to-url-encode-parameters-in-asp-net-mvc).
However, when I pass something else than %5C (e.g. %20 for space or %25 for % or %92 for apostrophe) it is working (breakpoint hit and correct result).

I know that I could use `?parameter=EncodedUsername`, which is working, but username is only one possibility, so I don't want to use this way if it's not necessary as I do not have backslashes in every case.

My Route looks like this:
`[HttpGet("{firstParameter}/{usernameWithDomainAndBackslash}")]`

Comment: [(Please) Stop Using Unsafe Characters in URLs](https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/). Why not just design your URLs to take domain and user name as separate placeholders so you can avoid the problem of passing the backslash altogether? `[HttpGet("{firstParameter}/{username}/{domain?}")]`

Comment: this is unfortunately not a solution as we do not only have usernames and domains as parameter but different search-parameters. As the backslash is an unsafe character, we decided to leave out the domain as, for us, the username is unique enough.

Answer (score 1):

Try use DoubleEscaping for backslash.

1. Modify your web.config:

   ```
   <configuration>
     <!--
       Configure your application settings in appsettings.json. Learn more at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=786380
     -->
     <system.web>
       <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters=""/>
     </system.web>

     <system.webServer>
       <security>
         <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true"></requestFiltering>
       </security>
       <handlers>
         <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
       </handlers>
       <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
     </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
   ```
2. For /, it will be encoded to '%252F' (%2F -> %252F)
3. Send the request to Server side, the decode it there.